# Is it possible to float a div to the bottom of its container (that has padding)?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to be able to float a div to the bottom of a container.  I'm using absolute positioning to accomplish this:

```css
#outer {
  background: lightblue;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  }

#inner {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id=outer>
  <div id=inner>BLAH BLAH</div>
  </div>
```

In the above, in order for the positioning to respect the border at the bottom of the outer container, I have to repeat the `20px` padding with `bottom: 20px`.  My issue is that this is a violation of the DRY principle - I don't want this to break when I change one of the two numbers.

An example that does respect padding is `float`.  If I `float` left or right, it only floats up to the padding.

I suspect I could use  preprocessor with variables (like LESS?) - but excluding that, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, flexbox of course but I'm not sure how extensible this will be.

```css
#outer {
  background: lightblue;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
#inner {
  background: red;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id=outer>
  <div id=inner>BLAH BLAH</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use margins instead of paddings?

```css
#outer {
  background: lightblue;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  }

#inner {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id=outer>
  <div id=inner>BLAH BLAH</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the css "`bottom: 0;`" in the child element.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to just go with another `div` before the `#inner` div that takes the `min-height` attribute:

```css
#outer {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 20px;
  }

#beforeinner {
  min-height: 100px;
  }

#inner {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id=outer>
  <div id=beforeinner></div>
  <div id=inner>BLAH BLAH</div>
</div>
```